# I want all users which doesn't match condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get all users where tag_it is not equal to 10

**user table:**

```
id | firstname  | lastname
1  | John       | Doe
2  | Test       | User
3  | Hello      | World
```

**user_tags table:**

```
id | tag_id     | user_id      
1  | 10         | 1    
2  | 10         | 2     
3  | 11         | 2
```

This is what i am trying

```
SELECT
    users.id
FROM
    users
    JOIN user_tags ut ON ut.user_id = users."id"
    AND ut.tag_id <> 10
WHERE
    users.id IN (1,2,3)
```

Expected output is 3.

Comment: Should a user with both tag_id 10 and tag_id 11 be returned or not?

Comment: No user 2 has tag_id 10  so it should not return 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM user_tags ut
    WHERE ut.user_id = u.id
    AND ut.tag_id = 10
)
```

Comment: Not possible with joins?

Comment: You must add a condition of not existence because JOIN check for each row, instead you want to know if all over the rows don't exist that combination

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with JOIN. IMHO Not Exists is a better solution but not necessary.

```
select id
  from (select u.id,ut.tag
          from users   u
          left join user_tag ut
            on u.id = ut.user_id 
                and ut.tag = 10
          where u.id in (1,2,3) 
       ) uut
where tag is null;
```